# How to resolve the conflict between 2 plugins created via Lightweight method in shopware?

Tags: vue.js, layout, plugins, backend, shopware

I have created a plugin. There is a backend listing form my plugin. so I have done this by using vue.js (https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/lightweight-backend-modules/)

There are no issues with the first plugin.

I have created another plugin. this plugin also has backend listing. I have created layout.tpl in my plugins _base folder.

But the problem is the 2nd plugin also loading the layout.tpl of the first plugin.

How to resolve this issue?

I have cleared the cache. But no hope.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have fixed this issue by adding the following line of code in the backend controller.

$this->get('Template')->setTemplateDir([]);

--------Function------

```
public function preDispatch() {
    $this->get('Template')->setTemplateDir([]);
    $this->get('template')->addTemplateDir(__DIR__ . '/../../Resources/views/');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should always "prefix" your views directory with an additional directory named like your plugin. Like this: `Resources/views/backend/my_plugin_name/layout.tpl`
With this you should not have the problem that one plugin uses the other plugins template file.

Best regards from Schöppingen

Michael Telgmann